# Adding an outer reference to a dynamic event handler

Tags: jquery

I have a function that created and I want the id to be passed into the dynamic click event handler. The object is gone and the counter value is always the last incremented value. I think there is a way to pass it in, but I cant figure it out.

Here is my demo code... http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/r62jJ/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
(function(){
$('#chartContainer').empty().attr("style", "overflow: hidden;");
var office = [];
var len = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = {
        officeTitle: 'Office:'+i,
        officeId: i,
        resizeable: true
    };
    office.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0; i < office.length; i++) {

    var chartHtml = $("<div>")
    .attr("id", "chartContainer" + i)
    .attr("style", "margin-top:20px;");

    $('#chartContainer').append(chartHtml);

    var officeLabel = $("<div>")
    .attr("style", "background-color:#eee;cursor:pointer;")
    .html(office[i]["officeTitle"] + ':' + office[i]["officeId"] )
    .click(function(){
        alert(i);
        alert(office[i]["officeId"])
    });

    $('#chartContainer' + i).append(officeLabel);
}
```

})();

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
(function(index) {
    var officeLabel = $("<div>")
        .attr("style", "background-color:#eee;cursor:pointer;")
        .html(office[index]["officeTitle"] + ':' + office[index]["officeId"] )
        .click(function(){
            alert(office[index]["officeId"])
        });
    $('#chartContainer' + index).append(officeLabel);
})(i);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aNmt/)

Comment: Very nice. I didn't think of adding another closure. I did end up figuring out a solution of adding a dynamic object as the first argument to the click handler... http://jsfiddle.net/8aNmt/

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do :

```
$(function(){
    $('#chartContainer').empty().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    $.each([0,1,2,3,4], function(i, num) {
        var chartHtml   = $('<div>', {id: 'chartContainer' + num, style: 'margin-top : 20px'}),
            officeLabel = $("<div>", {style: 'background-color:#eee; cursor:pointer;',
                                      html : 'Office'+ num + ':' + num,
                                      on: {
                                            click: function( event ) {
                                               alert(num);
                                            }
                                          }
                                     });

        $('#chartContainer').append(chartHtml);
        $('#chartContainer' + num).append(officeLabel);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r62jJ/5/)